# xmldocument could not format if specify PreserveWhitespace

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add an element into a xml and save, I'm using the XmlDocuemnt. My xml likes this :

```
  <a>
    <b>asd</b>

    <c>as</c>
  </a>
```

I want to keep the blank lines, so I specify the PreserveWhitespace = true; but when I append my created node with AppendChild(singlePropertyNode) and save, the newly added elements all in a line, below is what I want it looks like:

```
<a>
  <b>asd</b>

  <c>as</c>
  <newNodes>
    <addedNode>reserve</addedNode>
  </newNodes>
</a>
```

if I remove the PreserveWhitespace = true it will format well, but I do want to keep those blank lines.

Also post the sample code ；

```
        string content = "<a>\r\n  <b>asd</b>\r\n\r\n  <c>as</c>\r\n</a>";

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xml.LoadXml(content);

        var nodeC = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//a");

        XmlElement newNodes = xml.CreateElement("newNodes", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
        XmlElement addedNode = xml.CreateElement("addedNode", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
        addedNode.InnerText = "reserve";
        newNodes.AppendChild(addedNode);

        nodeC.AppendChild(newNodes);
        xml.Save(@"d:\test.xml");
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you have a few XML fragments, not an XML. I wonder why you want this special, irregular formatting in the first place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: thx guys for you patience, I have edited the question and posted the sample code.